# Flask Method View: How templates access PUT and Delete methods

Tags: python, flask

I have the following List and Detail View in which i can access the "GET" and "POST" by accessing there url rules. Note That: GET and POST are easily accessible as by GET and POST request.

But the problem is when I want to access the PUT and DELETE methods from templates, there exist no example in Flask Documentation that help to do so.

```
class ListView(MethodView):

  def get_context(self):
    form = CourseForm(request.form)
    courses = Course.query.order_by('timestamp desc').all()
    if courses is None:
      abort(404)
    context = {
      "courses" : courses,
      "form" : form
    }
    return context

  def get(self):
    context = self.get_context()
    return render_template('courses/list.html', **context)

  def post(self):
    context = self.get_context()
    form = context.get('form')

    if form.validate():
      course = Course(title=form.title.data, coursetype=form.coursetype.data)
      db.session.add(course)
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('courses.list'))

    return render_template('courses/list.html', **context)
```

For Show/Get, Update/PUT and DELETE Methods I did the following,but if i use 'get' method in Detail view for Show I will not able to use it for PUT as:

```
class DetailView(MethodView):

  def get_context(self, course_id):
    form = CourseForm(request.form)
    course = Course.query.filter_by(id=course_id).first()
    if course is None:
      abort(404)
    context = {
      "course": course,
      "form": form
    }
    return context

  def get(self, course_id):
    context = self.get_context(course_id)
    return render_template('courses/detail.html', **context)


  def post(self, course_id):
    context = self.get_context(course_id)

    return render_template('courses/detail.html', **context)

  def delete(self, course_id):
    context = self.get_context(course_id)
```

I again implement the following code to get the functionality of PUT as follow:

```
class EditView(MethodView):
  def get_context(self, course_id):
    form = CourseForm(request.form)
    course = Course.query.filter_by(id=course_id).first()
    if course is None:
      abort(404)
    context = {
      "course": course,
      "form": form
    }
    return context

  def get(self, course_id):
    context = self.get_context(course_id)
    form = context.get('form')
    course = context.get('course')

    form.title.data = course.title
    form.coursetype.data = course.coursetype

    return render_template('courses/edit.html', **context)

  def post(self, course_id):
    context = self.get_context(course_id)
    form = context.get('form')
    course = context.get('course')

    if form.validate():
      course.title=form.title.data
      course.coursetype=form.coursetype.data
      db.session.add(course)
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('courses.detail', course_id=course_id))

    return render_template('courses/detail.html', )
```

I want to Implement the functionality of EditView and DetailView togather in a single class as both uses course_id. and also suggest me the solution for DELETE.

The followings are url rule:

```
courses.add_url_rule('/', view_func=ListView.as_view('list'))
courses.add_url_rule('/<int:course_id>/', view_func=DetailView.as_view('detail'))
courses.add_url_rule('/edit/<int:course_id>/', view_func=EditView.as_view('edit'))
```

Note That: I want to access these functions from template.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The problem is web browsers do not usually deal with PUT and DELETE methods. These are usually called from an API. You would usually just return JSON and STATUS to say how it went.

Comment: so what would be the solution, should i need to make a new url for this, i don't want to make more url rules, already made three, this task should be completed in 2nd url rule.

Comment: If you want to use the site from a browser you will have to have another URL. for example /<int:course_id>/delete to remove it.

Comment: Thank you #Joe but my problem is that, I only want a single url as courses/<int:course_id> for PUT SHOW and DELETE from template. 
What is the benefit of using METHOD VIEW, if I have to make so much classes and urls.

Comment: They are useful just not in a browser. DELETE can be called from curl, jquery, requests etc, but browsers dont offer an easy method for send that to the server. Browsers mainly deal with GET and POST. In a browser there is no easy answer